# Passing a pointer of a variable as a parameter that is based on a template

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointers

I am probably making this more confusing than it needs to be but I am trying to figure out what the best practice is when dealing with templates and passing them by reference.

I have a class template called `IOQueue`. I created a `IOQueue<std::string>` in my `main`. I want to pass a pointer to another class that will be interacting with said queue. Here is what am I looking at:

main.cpp

```
IOQueue<std::string> *DecompressLogQueue;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    CompressFile cp(DecompressLogQueue);
    cp.Compress(9);

    return 0;
}
```

Now this is where I am kind of confused... In my CompressFile class, is there a cleaner and more ethical approach to passing this pointer? This is what I am looking at now.

```
CompressFile::CompressFile(IOQueue<std::string> *DecompressLogQueue) 
{
    CompressFile::DecompressLogQueue = DecompressLogQueue;
}
```

If I inherited my `IOQueue` template in CompressFile like so

```
class CompressFile : public IOQueue<string>
{
...
```

Couldn't I do something along the lines of

```
CompressFile::CompressFile(const T& DecompressLogQueue)
```

I know this probably wouldn't compile.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `CompressFile`'s constructor to only take a parameter of type `IOQueue<T>*`, where `T` is non-specific, you can use this:

```
class CompressFile
{
  public:
    template<typename T>
    CompressFile(IOQueue<T>* DecompressLogQueue)
    {
        // Will accept a pointer to an IOQueue with any template parameter.
        // ...
    }

    // ...  
};
```

If you want the constructor to take a parameter of any templated type, which has one template parameter, you can use this:

```
class CompressFile
{
  public:
    template<template<typename> class T, typename TParam>
    CompressFile(T<TParam>* DecompressLogQueue)
    {
        // Will accept a pointer to any class with one template parameter.
        // ...
    }

    // ...  
};
```

If you want something more complex, you'll likely need to use more complicated template magic, possibly involving some of the helpers from `<type_traits>`.

Note that in both cases, only the constructor itself needs to be templated; `CompressFile` doesn't need to have any template parameters for this to work.

---

Now, having said that, let's look at your other questions:

> In my CompressFile class, is there a cleaner and more ethical approach to passing this pointer?

You can try passing a reference instead of a pointer, or passing a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer.

```
template<template<typename> class T, typename TParam>
CompressFile::CompressFile(T<TParam>& DecompressLogQueue);

// ....

IOQueue<std::string> DecompressLogQueue;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CompressFile cp(DecompressLogQueue);
    // The compiler will handle the pointer syntax for you.
}
```

> If I inherited my IOQueue template in CompressFile like so
>
> ```
> class CompressFile : public IOQueue<string>
> {
> ...
> ```
>
> Couldn't I do something along the lines of
>
> ```
> CompressFile::CompressFile(const T& DecompressLogQueue)
> ```

Unfortunately, to my knowledge C++ lacks simple syntax, a keyword, or a standardised macro for using a parent class' type like that, so you would still need to type it out.  If you want to shorten the name, try using a `typedef`.

```
typedef IOQueue<std::string> IOQSS;

CompressFile::CompressFile(const IOQSS& DecompressLogQueue);
```

---

If this isn't what you were asking about, could you please clarify your question?